# Classifying spaces of finitely presented groups with torsion elements

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a finitely presented group that has a torsion element. Can the classifying space $K(\Gamma,1)$ be homotopic to a finite-dimensional manifold?
If yes, what is the simplest example?

Comment: The answer is no, because the presence of torsion forces $\Gamma$ to have infinite cohomological dimension. See e.g. Ken Brown's "Cohomology of groups", Chapter VIII.2.

Comment: Note that there is a version of classifying spaces $\underline{E}G$ where $G$ acts so that compact (i.e. finite) subgroups have (weakly) contractible fixed point sets. Sometimes groups with torsion can have finite-dimensional $\underline{E}G$. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1292018

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible.  Let $B$ be a space of type $K(\Gamma,1)$ and of dimension $d<\infty$, and let $E$ be the universal cover, which is contractible.  Then for any $A\leq\Gamma$ we see that $E/A$ is a $K(A,1)$ and has finite dimension, so the group cohomology $H^i(A)$ vanishes for $i>d$.  However, for $n>1$ the group cohomology of $C_n$ is nonzero in all even degrees, so $\Gamma$ cannot contain $C_n$, so $\Gamma$ must be torsion-free.